# seqmining: how to calculate frequency of a sequence on python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `pymining` on Python to generate frequent sequences from my dataset. My code below appears to be working well:

```
from pymining import seqmining
seqs = ( 'caabc', 'abcb', 'cabc', 'abbca')
freq_seqs = seqmining.freq_seq_enum(seqs, 2)
sorted(freq_seqs)
```

However, when i want to use it with my dataset:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from pymining import seqmining

    def importdata():
    filename = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/memoire/sequences-code.csv', sep= ';', header = None)

data=importdata()
seqs = data
freq_seqs = seqmining.freq_seq_enum(seqs, 2)
sorted(freq_seqs)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

this is all the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-19e2af14465a> in <module>()
      8 data=importdata()
      9 seqs = data
---> 10 freq_seqs = seqmining.freq_seq_enum(seqs, 2)
     11 sorted(freq_seqs)
     12 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymining\seqmining.py in freq_seq_enum(sequences, min_support)
      9     '''
     10     freq_seqs = set()
---> 11     _freq_seq(sequences, tuple(), 0, min_support, freq_seqs)
     12     return freq_seqs
     13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymining\seqmining.py in _freq_seq(sdb, prefix, prefix_support, min_support, freq_seqs)
     16     if prefix:
     17         freq_seqs.add((prefix, prefix_support))
---> 18     locally_frequents = _local_freq_items(sdb, prefix, min_support)
     19     if not locally_frequents:
     20         return

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymining\seqmining.py in _local_freq_items(sdb, prefix, min_support)
     28     items = defaultdict(int)
     29     freq_items = []
---> 30     for entry in sdb:
     31         visited = set()
     32         for element in entry:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: I put the error in an answer

Comment: `importdata` is returning `None`, causing `freq_seq_enum` to complain. The `importdata` function you defined has no return statement, which is why it returns `None`.

Comment: i added the return statement and i still have the error

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change you can make to your code is to get rid of `importdata`, which is just a wrapper on `pd.read_csv`. Try:

```
filename = 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/memoire/sequences-code.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', header=None)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: the error becomes : ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: This can mean that `sequences-code.csv` is not present.

Comment: @chayma, can you try something very simple? Open a new Python interpreter, import pandas, and only run the two lines above? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-55d82acf567e> in <module>()
      1 from pandas import read_csv
      2 
----> 3 filename = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/memoire/sequences-code.csv')
      4 data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', header=None)

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: can i send you the dataset and try to execute the code?

Comment: @chayma, what do you think "name 'pd' is not defined" indicates?